# Website Template Upload to Github

Tags: github

I am exploring Github. 
Yesterday I tried to upload basic site and successfully did it with the help of different sites, it works. But right now I am exploring for more. 
Is it possible to add database so that they can add comments on my page?, anyways I am only a novice programmer so that my question I think is out of the blue. I've seen different forums and people there said it can't be done but I just want to know if it is possible.

[I created this sample page so that it is not difficult to understand my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqpT0.png)

Comment: Why are you referring Github here? Do you want to upload a website and a database on the Internet?

Comment: Yes I want to upload my website and database on the internet using Github.

Comment: Github is a website where people upload repositories. Github is not used as a server mate. You must use some hosting, either shared or a server. Google free hosting and you'll have a lot many websites. Many hosting services do allow linking github repositories directly though but that doesn't mean that gitbhub is used as a server.

Comment: http://wrines.github.io/WEB/

Comment: that is the URL of my sample site uploaded inside github

Comment: I wasn't aware about that man, I am sorry.

Comment: ok sir. thank you for your time. :-)

Comment: Don't call me sir bro, we are the same. I suggest that you should use a free hosting website to continue your journey. Websites like hostinger.in etc. provide free hosting and you can manage database and all there - MySQL.

Comment: Ok bro:-)...how about free webhosting and free domain name?. can you recommend site for me.

Comment: http://www.freenom.com/ = You can use this for free domain name

Comment: and hostinger.in for free hosting = It is easy to use - Apache server shared hosting.

Comment: thank you buddy. I got it already:-)

Comment: You might want to use disqus for comments.D

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) (which is what I assume you're referring to) does not provide a database or other backend services; it simply hosts static HTML and CSS files that you provide in a specially-named repository. If you want to add interactive features that require a database, you'll need to move to a full-fledged Web hosting service that provides more than just static pages. However, if all you want to do is create a blog (which I'm guessing might be the reason why you're interested in users adding comments), GitHub does allow you to [use the Jekyll Framework](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/), which can be used to generate a blog or other semi-dynamic, template-based website.